# Object of class Magento\Framework\DataObject could not be converted to string

Tags: magento2.3.3

When i tried to click on some subcategory links on the navigation bar it gives the error

Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\DataObject could not be converted to string in /home/ampscooters/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php on line 247

I have upgraded to magento 2.3.3 from magento 2.2.4 and this issue is raised,

I have also checked the file Escaper.php on line 247.

[image]

Although this issue is with some sub-categories and others are opening fine.

Answer (score 4):

Happend same to me. When I try to click in a sub-category who have product with a review, give me the same error. Error comes from this file:

`vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml`

In line 13, (`$rating = $block->getRatingSummary()`) function getRatingSummary return me an array or an objetct and this give me error.

Why happend this? The file `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml` is similar but not give me error.

Comment: Hi, So how did you solve this

Answer (score 3):

Need to serialize `<?php $rating = serialize($block->getRatingSummary()) ?>` in `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml` on line 13.